# Share on FB page showing image that I didnt included in my site

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am currently working on http://rightinfo.co.in
When I am trying to share this site on a FB page it is showing an image that I have not included in my site.
I have tried by adding ?v=1 to the url and url shortner services.
In facebook debugger also , the image is not showing. But in actual sharing , unknown image is showing.
Please help me to solve this

Thanks

Comment: Add code to elaborate more

Comment: I am just copying and paste the url in Facebook for sharing

Comment: ya know but share code so i can help you.

Comment: When I am opening the image in a new tab. the url is,
https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDNTL3vPzcAz-tD&w=300&h=300&url=http%3A%2F%2Frightinfo.co.in%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2FMorpheus%2Fimg%2Fportfolio%2Ffolio01-preview.jpg&cfs=1&ext=png2jpg

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `og:image` (see [here](http://ogp.me/#metadata)) meta tag is set. This tag defines the image, which will be shown on facebook.
To change this image, try to edit this tag, take a look at the theme settings.
Another way is to change/delete the image itself, e.g. via FTP.
You can find it here: WEBROOT/wp-content/themes/Morpheus/img/portfolio/folio01-preview.jpg
Btw, I see you are using wordpress, I'd consider using a SEO plugin, which makes a proper use of the og-tags as explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags)

Answer (score 0):

You have issue with tags Please check this facebook debugger it explains alot [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frightinfo.co.in%2F)